# What or where is the Definition of Flow Content in HTML 5?

Tags: html

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1 gives a list of Flow Content elements (3.2.5.1.2 Flow content). But other items appear to be flow but are not in said list.

For example, the <th> element is described as flow by http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/tabular-data.html#the-th-element.

So, is there a definitive list anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comprehensive list which clearly states all elements falling under the category **Flow Content** does not exist.  Your link, or the same content on MDN is the answer to your question.

Evidence: From the link you provided we can see there is no clear line between the various types of Content.  A good example of this is comparing Sectioning Content with Flow Content, which I find to be a lot easier to read through on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content).  Note that at the top of that page they state,

> Each HTML element belongs to zero, one, ***or multiple content models***, each setting rules that the element's content must follow in an HTML-conformant document.

While I agree this is undesirable from a developer and IA standpoint - I cannot venture a guess without getting opinionated or speculating as to why a list is provided while at the same time is missing elements referenced elsewhere as Flow Content, but if interested please feel free to pm me to discuss.

Relevant:
My team has had the same issue attempting to validate our html5 before giving it a stamp of approval.  As the lead I quickly found out during this process that making an educated guess on what might fall within **Flow Content's** definition was the best choice.  In the end the main issue I have with these definitions is that there is no clear line between Flow content and Sectioning Content.  In the end we wound up just looking at the HTML outline in an ARIA compliant/assistive browser to determine consequences of our coding choices with respect to Content Sectioning.  You can find out more about this at the following places:

http://html5doctor.com/outlines/